How to create additional columns based on the values from select statement?
I have a select statement like this:
SELECT 
    ID, NAME, AGE, LOCATION, GPF, ACCNO, 
    CASE
        WHEN .... AS Indicator1, 
    CASE
        WHEN .... AS Indicator2, ....
FROM 
    EMPLOYEES

I have couple of Indicator columns that are having complex case statements.
Next, based on the indicators I need to create some more columns.
Example:
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID, NAME, AGE, LOCATION, GPF, ACCNO, 
        CASE WHEN .... AS Indicator1, 
        CASE WHEN .... AS Indicator2, 
        ....
    FROM 
        EMPLOYEES
)
SELECT
    *, 
    CASE 
        WHEN Indicator1 = 0 AND Indicator2 = 1 
            THEN 'SDM1'.... 
    END AS Class1, 
    CASE 
        WHEN .....
    END
FROM 
    CTE

Another way to do this is to fill the first select into temp table, then perform select on the temp table and reference the Indicator columns.
Example:
SELECT 
    ID, NAME, AGE, LOCATION, GPF, ACCNO, 
    CASE WHEN .... END AS Indicator1, 
    CASE WHEN .... END AS Indicator2,
    ....
INTO
    #TMP1
FROM
    EMPLOYEES;

SELECT 
    *, 
    CASE 
        WHEN Indicator1 = 0 AND Indicator2 = 1 
            THEN 'SDM1'.... 
    END AS Class1, 
    CASE WHEN ..... END
FROM 
    #TMP1

Some times I need to use the output of this level - that is Class1, .... to add a few new columns, this resulting in 3rd level.
This seems to be time consuming to run using cte or temp tables. I was wondering if is there any other approach allowed by SQL that I can try to refer to calculated columns (like case statements) from the SELECT query?

CASE in T-SQL is an expression - not a "statement" ...

Put them into a Cross Apply

Cross apply can't refer to an ALIAS in the main SELECT, so, do you mean add the case expression's into cross apply?

Cross apply can't refer to an ALIAS in the main SELECT not sure what you mean with this

In select query if I have concat(col1, col2) as test, then in the OUTER APPLY I can't refer to test.

Put the stuff into cross apply. For example: select x.calc1, y.calc2, * from maintable cross apply (select <somecomplexcalc> as calc1) x cross apply (select x.calc1 + <another calc> as calc2) y...

Correct and thanks for this, but if I do the <somecomplexcalc> as calc1 in the main select query, then it can't be used in cross apply.

Nope, but you knew that already

No I don't know why calc1 can't be used in cross or outer apply. Do you?

I didn't write why anywhere, but if you really want to know, it's because of how sql is logically processed, the SELECT part if done pretty late in the game, so the aliases are available for ORDER BY, not for the inner tables.

Are these calculations always the same?  Do you need to see the results more than once?  Create a new related table, bite bullet on populating from existing data, begin populating/editing the data in the new table based on new rows or updates to the employees table.  Join the two when querying for your report.  This offloads the time and work to perform the calculation to your app layer, and the users will not see/feel the extra time the way you do trying to run them all at once.
